# Query with sp_send_dbmail not working with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following declared variables

```
DECLARE
    @start_date NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @end_date NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query_string NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

I then set the variables to the following values

```
set @start_date = CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 110)
    set @end_date = CONVERT(nvarchar, DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETDATE()), 110)
    set @query_string = 
    '
        SELECT 
               WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID,
               LEFT (PART.DESCRIPTION, 3) as DESCRIPTION,
               WORK_ORDER.PART_ID,
               WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_QTY, 
               WORK_ORDER.RECEIVED_QTY, 
               WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_RLS_DATE ,
               WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE, 
               PART_SITE.ENGINEERING_MSTR, 
               WORK_ORDER.PRINTED_DATE, 
               PART.USER_7

            FROM (WORK_ORDER 
            LEFT JOIN PART ON WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = PART.ID) 
            LEFT JOIN PART_SITE ON WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = PART_SITE.PART_ID 
                   
            WHERE 
                   (((WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID) Like ''WO%'') 
                   AND ((WORK_ORDER.PART_ID) Like ''F-%''
                   OR (WORK_ORDER.PART_ID) Like ''R-%'') 
                   AND ((WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_RLS_DATE) >= ' + @start_date + ' AND WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_RLS_DATE <= ' + @end_date + '))
                   AND PART.USER_7 like ''AEGIS%''

            ORDER BY WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_RLS_DATE'
```

When I try to call the `@query_string` in my `sp_send_dbmail` procedure it doesn't populate with any data even though the same query populates ~20 rows just querying the database. Here is how I try and execute the dbmail procedure

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name='Default_Mail',
            @recipients='my_email@gmail.com',
            @subject='FLX Orders Updated',
            @query=@query_string,
            @execute_query_database = 'VISUAL',
            @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
            @query_attachment_filename = 'Updated FLX Order.txt'
```

I suspect that it is an issue with my `@query_string` parameters as I am trying to pass them into the string. Any help is greatly appreciated. The output I am receiving is 0 rows.

Comment: `@start_date NVARCHAR(MAX)`? How many dates are you aware of that are made up of 1 billion~ characters? I know of none.

Comment: Run your script (exactly as posted - the first part) in a SSMS window and looked at the content of your dynamic sql string. You need to embed string delimiters in your generated query around your date literals.

Comment: To add to that - your date literal will be interpreted as a number using math (09-14-2020 =  -2025). And you should be using a convert style that not be misinterpreted regardless of connection or user settings - 112 not 110.

Comment: @SMor This fixed my issue, thank you. Do you want to add it as an answer? All I did was change ```((WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_RLS_DATE) >= ''' + @start_date + ''' AND WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_RLS_DATE <= ''' + @end_date + '''))``` I also changed the ```NVARCHAR(MAX)``` to ```NVARCHAR(20)```